# The functions are not working/improve the program

Tags: java

```
/*
* Write a program to determine is an entered date (day/month/year) is valid.
* As part of the program write and use the following routines:
*  - validDate() which takes a year, month and day and returns whether or not
*  the date is valid
*  - daysInMonth() which takes a month (between 1 and 12) and year, and returns
*    the number of days in the month.
*  - isLeapYear() which takes a year and return whether or not it is a leap year.my solution:
*/
import java.util.*;
public class Program{
    public static final int MONTH_THIRTY =30;
    public static final int OTHER_MONTH = 31;
    public static final int FEB =28;
    public static final int LEAP_FEB = 29;
    public static final int MONTHS =12;
    public static void main(String [] args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter date (day/month/year)");
        sc.useDelimiter("/");
        int day = sc.nextInt();
        int month = sc.nextInt();
        int year = sc.nextInt(); 
        System.out.println(day+month+year);
        validDate(day,month,year);
        daysinMonth(month,year);
        ifLeapYear(year);
    }
     public static void validDate(int date, int month, int year){
         if((date>0 && date<32) && (year>0) && (month>0 && month<=12)){
             System.out.println("True");
         }else {
             System.out.println("False");
         }
     }
     public static int daysinMonth(int month, int year){
         int daysinmonth=31;
         if(year>0 && month<=MONTHS){
             switch(month){
                 case 2 : boolean leapyear = ((year%4==0)&& (year%100!=0)||(year%400==0));
                  daysinmonth = leapyear ? LEAP_FEB :FEB;
                     break;
                 case 4:
                 case 6:
                 case 9:
                 case 11: daysinmonth = MONTH_THIRTY;
                 default : daysinmonth = OTHER_MONTH;
            }
         }
        return daysinmonth;
     }
     public static boolean ifLeapYear(int year){
         if((year%4==0)&& (year%100!=0)||(year%400==0)){
             return true;
         }else{
             return false;
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: I see no question here, just an assignment which SO doesn't do

Comment: The `validDate (... )` method is not full proof. Since for `31st of February, 2015` it will return true, likewise for many other dates. Instead other methods must act as an subsidiary to this method to tell if the date is valid or not.

Comment: in the `validDate(...)` call the `daysInMonth` method and check the result against the day.  And the `ifLeapYear` method should be called in the `daysInMonth` method (instead of having the same logic twice in your code) ... and a `break`is missing in your switch statement (before 'default:')

Answer (score 1):

With some small fixes your program does work.
Next time ask a specific question (not only "this isn't working").

As said in the comment you need to do some small adjustments:

in the `validDate(...)` call the `daysInMonth` method and check the result against the day. And the `ifLeapYear` method should be called in the `daysInMonth` method (instead of having the same logic twice in your code)

```
public class Program {

public static final int MONTH_THIRTY = 30;
public static final int OTHER_MONTH = 31;
public static final int FEB = 28;
public static final int LEAP_FEB = 29;
public static final int MONTHS = 12;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter date (day/month/year)");
    String nextLine = sc.nextLine();
    String[] split = nextLine.split("/");
    int day = Integer.valueOf(split[0]);
    int month = Integer.valueOf(split[1]);
    int year = Integer.valueOf(split[2]);
    System.out.println("day:" + day + " month: " + month + " year: " + year);
    validDate(day, month, year);

}

public static void validDate(int date, int month, int year) {
    if ((year > 0) && (month > 0 && month <= 12) && (date > 0 && date <= daysinMonth(month, year))) {
        System.out.println("Date is valid");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Date is not valid");
    }
}

public static int daysinMonth(int month, int year) {

    switch (month) {
    case 2:
        return isLeapYear(year) ? LEAP_FEB : FEB;
    case 4:
    case 6:
    case 9:
    case 11:
        return MONTH_THIRTY;
    default:
        return OTHER_MONTH;
    }

}

public static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
    if ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
}
```